# Difference between /* and /**? (Commenting contracts)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, tokens, remix

In some contracts I saw comments that are made with "/*" and "/**".
For me the only change would be in the IDE like Remix, that the color changes from green (/*) to blue (/**). I until now liked the "/**" more but now got an error and do not understand what the "/**" does. Following code:

```
/**
 * @event Transfers token
 */
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```

Gives me

> DocstringParsingError: Doc tag @event not valid for functions.

but replacing "@event" with "@dev"

```
/**
 * @dev Transfers token
 */
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```

Works

 and using @event above almost anything else

```
/**
 * @event Transfers token
 */
public uint anynumber;
```

Also works.

So as I understand, in "/**" is more than just commenting. What is that and why does "@event" not work above an Event even it is just a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the [Ethereum Natural Specification Format](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Natural-Specification-Format).

> Documentation is inserted above the function following the doxygen notation of either one or multiple lines starting with /// or a multiline comment starting with /** and ending with */.

In the specification `@dev` is an existing tag, and `@event` is not defined.

Comment: Oh great, thanks! Did not think that it has more functions than just comments. Sad I can't make comments in blue anymore without having more functions than wanted :D.